# How to multiple results from an Excel table reading multiple values from a column

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, vlookup

I have a table with this structure in an Excel spreedsheet:

TYPE    - COLOR   - PRICE
  DOGS    - brown      - $10 
  DOGS    - gray          - $12 
  DOGS    - white       - $11 
  DOGS    - black       - $10 
  DOGS    - red            - $13 
  CATS    - white        - $7 
  CATS    - black        - $5 
  CATS    - yellow          - $8 
CATS      - red             - $6

I need a formula to return all the prices from the table that match with the "COLORS INPUT:" (brown, black and white) by reading those colors sequentially from the cells under "COLORS INPUT:" and populating the prices under "PRICES RESULT:". Per example:

COLORS INPUT:
brown
black
white

PRICES RESULT:
$10 
$10 
$5 
$11 
$7

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Black corresponds to both $10 and $5, but you only have $10 next to it, while white corresponds to $7 and $11, but you show $5 as well.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values) for some ideas.